# Gitblit: Ability to delete branches from the web interface

Tags: git, gitblit

We are migrating our repositories from Stash to Gitblit.

I saw that there should be the possibility in Gitblit to delete branches of a repository in the web interface: https://github.com/gitblit/gitblit/issues/417.

But I cannot find this possibility on the web interface (I am owner of the repository).

Google and the Gitblit documentation could not enlighten me.
Does anybody know about this possibility?

Any hint or advice is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the repo summary page click the *all branches* link.  This will bring you to the repo's branches page.  If you have delete permissions for the repo you should have a *delete* link for each branch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but from the "branches" page (being pedantic, I have no "all branches" link), I have these options for each branch:  log | tree | raw | metrics | feed. But I cannot find a delete option. May this be a configuration issue? I am owner of the repo, so I usually should be able to delete it.

Comment: Ah, I see.  You have too few branches in your repo to make that link available and the "delete" links are not displayed on the summary page.  (I think the default is 5 branches on the summary page before the link is shown -- that might be configurable, can't remember.)

As a workaround you could manually replace "summary" of the url in the address bar with "branches".

Comment: OK. Thanks for this explanation. The branches link is indeed presenst, it's just called "branches" not "all branches" (I just wanted to be pedantically clear ;-) ). Now I see what you mean. It's OK now. Thanks again.

Comment: Good point.  But here are two links.  The "branches" link which I should have described and is always there and the "all branches" link which will be displayed beneath the branches table when there are more than 5 branches in the repo.